Ion Auth 4 - users() - You must set the database table to be used with your query
Converting app from CI3 to CI4 and IonAuth3 to IonAuth4
using code:
$users = $this->ionAuth->users(4)->result();
error:
You must set the database table to be used with your query.
Why I'm getting this error? I can use other IonAuth functions without errors
Tried to add protected $tables = 'users' in model, same error

you need to set the table name with e.g.: $builder = $db->table('your_ionAuth_table_name t1'); where t1 is an optional alias. see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#loading-the-query-builder
